# Use gsl on Mac 10.6.3

Tags: c++, macos, precompiled-headers, gsl

I recently have a project using GSL. After I installed the GSL package on Mac 10.6.3. I cannot compile my code.

The gsl lib is located at /usr/local/lib, and the head file located at /usr/local/.

When I compile my code I get the the following error. If I do not specify "-m32" in the makefile, it still gives the same error, just change "i386" to "x86_64". Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

```
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_multiroots.h>
```

By the way, should I include gsl like the above? actually I am quite new to programming.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_gsl_vector_get", referenced from:
  gsl_root_finding::print_state(unsigned long, gsl_multiroot_fdfsolver*)in test_guide.o
  gsl_root_finding::print_state(unsigned long, gsl_multiroot_fsolver*)in test_guide.o
  gsl_root_finding::mm_f(gsl_vector const*, void*, gsl_vector*)in test_guide.o
  gsl_root_finding::process(int, double*, double, double)in test_guide.o
  gsl_root_finding::mm_fdf(gsl_vector const*, void*, gsl_vector*, gsl_matrix*)in test_guide.o
  gsl_root_finding::mm_df(gsl_vector const*, void*, gsl_matrix*)in test_guide.o
"_gsl_vector_set", referenced from:
  gsl_root_finding::mm_f(gsl_vector const*, void*, gsl_vector*)in test_guide.o
  gsl_root_finding::process(int, double*, double, double)in test_guide.o
  gsl_root_finding::mm_fdf(gsl_vector const*, void*, gsl_vector*, gsl_matrix*)in test_guide.o
  gsl_root_finding::mm_df(gsl_vector const*, void*, gsl_matrix*)in test_guide.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test_guide] Error 1
```

The build code:

```
CC = g++
OPT = -pg -g -I../include -L../libs -I../../Matrix-1.0/include -I../../bessel-1.1/include  -L../../Matrix-1.0/libs -L../../bessel-1.1/libs -L/usr/local/lib
LIBS =  -lfmm -lssi -lsparse -lbessel -lg2c -lgfortran -lgsl
.SUFFIXES : .o .cpp 

test_guide: test_guide.o
  ${CC} -o $@ ${OPT} test_guide.o ${LIBS}
```

Comment: What is the exact command you’re using to build your program?

Comment: Hello @Bavarious I attached the build code and hopes you can figure out the problem. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think you'll need to link with GSL's BLAS library as well. Your x86_64 undefined reference seems to imply as much (blas.o is the hint I'm going on). Just add

```
-lgslcblas
```

to your LIBS variable.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Where exactly do i add the -lgslcblas?. I did some hackish work around by locating the library in /usr/local/lib and adding it manually to the project.

Comment: In your makefile after the `LIBS` variable, or somewhere I don't know in XCode. I'm not familiar with Mac.